# How to read custom tags from file metadata [Java]

Tags: android, tags, metadata, mediastore

I'm trying to read some of the more obscure metadata tags from an audio file but I'm having no luck. To get the basic ones (title, year, artist, etc) I'm using the corresponding `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.X` and that works fine.

But some tags don't exist in the AudioColumns options. How can I read those? For example, how can I get tags like "PERFORMER", "WORK_TITLE", "RELEASE_DATE", etc?